# DBCC USEROPTIONS server/client

Tags: sql-server, locale

We are using MS SQL server 10.0, and running the DBCC options in two different user accounts, we get two different results. One has language us_english other as british. Where is the information stored on the server, is it possible to change it?

```
textsize    2147483647
language    us_english
dateformat  mdy
datefirst   7
lock_timeout    -1
quoted_identifier   SET
arithabort  SET
ansi_null_dflt_on   SET
ansi_warnings   SET
ansi_padding    SET
ansi_nulls  SET
concat_null_yields_null SET
isolation level read committed snapshot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, yes. This setting is set on the login that the connection is using and changes all sorts of subtle behavior. Dates are especially affected (first day of the week etc).

To view the default language settings for all logins run the following:

```
SELECT name, sp.default_language_name FROM master.sys.server_principals AS sp
```

That will show you the differences.

If you want to change the default language of a login use the following syntax:

```
 ALTER LOGIN LoginName WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english
```

Comment: So this information is specific to the group that loginName belongs?

Comment: Not exactly. In SQL a login is a way of allowing access to a SQL Instance. A login can be a Windows User, a Windows Group, or a SQL Login. If the login is mapped to a windows group then any settings (such as language) defined for that login apply to all Windows Users in this group that are accessing via this login. If that makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default language for some users is different. You can change the default language for a user with the following syntax:

```
ALTER USER UserName WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english;
```

For more info see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx).